# How to add image in box component EXTJs 3.4

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I want to add an image to a list. I'm using `xtype: "box"` as there is not image `xtype` in extjs 3.4.

Here is the code:

```
{
    xtype: 'box',
    width: 16,
    height: 16,
    cls: 'icon',
    listeners: {
        scope: this
    }
}
```

css:

```
.icon{
    background-image: url(../img/remove-icon.png);
}
```

But I dont see the icon getting rendered.

What I'm I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background image URL is not resolving correctly.

**Here is a POC code:**

app.js

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create({
        xtype: 'panel',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        title: 'Box Image Demo Panel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'box',
            width: 170,
            height: 170,
            cls: 'icon',
            listeners: {
                scope: this
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<style>
    .icon {
        background-image: url(http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/floating-action-button-ejemplo.png);
    }
</style>
```

**Here is working fiddle:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gdt

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (test.html):

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../ext-3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-3.4.0/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-3.4.0/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function() {

            Ext.create({
                xtype: 'window',
                title: 'Image',
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                layout: 'vbox',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'box',
                    width: 16,
                    height: 16,
                    autoEl: {
                        tag: 'img',
                        src: '../img/remove-icon.png'
                    }
                }]
            }).show();

        });
    </script>
    <title>'TEST'</title>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

Notes:
Tested with ExtJS 3.4.0.